# Unable to retrieve the field column of relation table ActiveDataProvider yii2

Tags: php, json, activerecord, yii2

I have a `users` table referenced to `orders` table, so in my `Users` model, relational method is declared like this:

```
public function getOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Orders::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

I have a function where I am constructing this query:

```
$stmt = Users::find()->select([
    'users.first_name', 'users.last_name',
    'users.user_id', 'orders.payment_method'
])->innerJoinWith('orders');
```

and will pass it to `ActiveDataProvider`'s `query` property:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $stmt,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => self::PER_PAGE,
    ],
]);
```

and returns the `$dataProvider`.

(NOTE: This function lives under a class that extends from `yii/rest/Controller`, so every function's returning data is expected to be in JSON content.)

However, when I call this function, only the fields of `users` is returned/selected, and keeps the `orders.payment_method` missing. This is what i need to get:

```
[
    {"first_name":"Gold","last_name":"Jacinto","user_id":1521,"payment_method":"CC"},
    {"first_name":"Gold","last_name":"Jacinto","user_id":1521,"payment_method":"COD"}
]
```

but getting this output instead:

```
[
    {"first_name":"Gold","last_name":"Jacinto","user_id":1521},
    {"first_name":"Gold","last_name":"Jacinto","user_id":1521}
]
```

Am I missing some process or anything that I should transform into? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Deep, I don't think we have the same problem there. Thanks.

Comment: current query result?

Comment: Hi @InsaneSkull, this is the current output:
    
    `[
        {"first_name":"Gold","last_name":"Jacinto","user_id":1521},
        {"first_name":"Gold","last_name":"Jacinto","user_id":1521}
    ]`

Comment: According to your relation there is many payment method for single user and there is no join in your query.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, I forgot to attach the join, but there is a join there, but still getting the same response. So did you mean that it is just normal to get that output when I have a many-to-many relationship?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use Rest you must use extendFields.

In your user model class add function

```
  public function extraFields()
    {
        return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::extraFields(),[
            'orders'=>'orders',
        ]); 
    }
```

then in request add to url ?expand=orders
e.g.: http://localhost/users?expand=orders

more is here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html